# Bootstrap modal issue when opening another modal from button inside first modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that opens up and displays information. In the modal, there is a register button. Upon clicking that button, it closes the first modal and opens a new "registration" modal. The issue arises when I close that modal, the modal disappears but the background remains opaque and I can't access the page behind it. Here is my code. I would like the modal to close fully upon clicking any button or off the modal itself as the default behavior would.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="register-for-fame" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerForFame">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="registerForFame">Register For Fame</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        Some text
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        more text
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary flow-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Not right now
        </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary register-user" data-dismiss="modal">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".register-user">want to register!</a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="modal fade register-user" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content padding-sides">
      <h3 class="center">Register!</h3>
      </br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" size="30" placeholder="Username:">
      </br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" size="30" placeholder="Password:">
      </br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="confirmation-password" size="30" placeholder="Confirm Password:">
      </br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email-address" size="30" placeholder="Email (optional):">
      </br>
      <p>some text</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary flow-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal">
        Not right now
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit-registration flow-right" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal">
        Register me!
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: jQuery plugin - https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary register-user" data-dismiss="modal">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".register-user">want to register!</a>
</button>
```

Look at your data-target (it is `register-user` class which your button has).

Change the target to `#register-user` and add `id="register-user"` to your second modal.